# Java query call to sybase db is not returning any value

Tags: java, websphere, sap-ase, jrules

This is my application request flow:

An XML request is going to service layer, where the XML got parsed and set the value in to a domain object build in java. Then the builded domain object validated against the rules in JRules.

While validating, there is a complex query call from JRules BOM method to the sybase database. This method call is returning the values in my DEV and SIT environments with out any issue . But fails to return the value in UAT environment for few requests.

I had a chance to check the UAT logs and what i found is, that particular query failing to return any value if it's execution time is more than 800 ms. I found for few requests whose execution time is less than 750ms is returning the values with out issue.
I couldn't see any errors related to query timeout.

Is any where at the websphere level settings or at sybase level settings(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_VALUE) affect this query execution to return nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason for this issue. It seems there is a dead lock happening in that particular query call. This was noticed in service log. We are planning to introduce a retry mechanism.